# What is the best way to code an array that has same keys as another array's values

Tags: php

I have two arrays as follows:

```
public $headers = [
    'user_id',
    'timestamp',
    'value',
];

protected $args = array('user_id' => array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
                                                      'options' => array('regexp' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/'), ),
                        'timestamp' => array('filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                                             'options' => "validateDate", ), ),
                        'value' => FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, );
```

The keys in the array args are the same values of the array headers.
How to avoid repeating the values here ?

Comment: More context perhaps as this really doesn't seem like a code review to me.  Is this a construct you are planning to use in `filter_input_array()` or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

I delete the keys from the args array, and I create a new array from combining both headers and args:

```
$argsVal = [ array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,'options' => array('regexp' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9_:.()\/]*$/'), ),
               array('filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK,'options' => "validateDate", ), FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, ];

$args = array_combine($headers,$argsVal);
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that the author can learn from your thought process.